# How to get transparent list view in javafx?

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, styling

I have a list view. I want to make the cells background transparent. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
.list-cell
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

But, the color of the cells remain white. I have tried the same with other colors. It works for other colors. But, it's not working for the transparent color. How can I get a transparent list-view?

Comment: Change to opacity on the list view.

Comment: But, wouldn't that mess up with the text opacity?

Comment: Well yes, perhaps it would help if you shared more code to explain for what effect you are aiming.

Comment: Even if the `list-cell` background is transparent, the background color is still white which is what you do not want. But, I can't still be sure if you do not share more code or an image of what you are looking for.

Comment: If you make the list cells transparent, then you will see through them to whatever is behind them: ie. the list view itself. If you make the list view transparent as well, then you will see whatever is behind it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make both the list-view and list-cell transparent.

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.list-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```